# ReactQuery in NextJs getStaticPaths

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

I would like to query an individual ID with `useQuery` hook, `getStaticPaths`, and `getStaticProps` in Next.js.
I achieved the whole list, however, I don't know how to get details for individual ID?
The code for the whole list of users is below:

```js
import { QueryClient, useQuery } from 'react-query';
import axios from 'axios'

export default function Index() {
    const { isLoading, data, isError, error } = useQuery('users', fetchUsers)

    if(isLoading){
        return <h2>Loading....</h2>
    }
    if(isError){
        return<h2>{error.message}</h2>
    }

    return (
        <>
            {
                data?.data.map(user => {
                    return <div key={user.id}>
                        <Link href={`users/${user.id}`}>.{user.name}.    </Link>
                    </div>
                })
            }
        </>
    )
}

export async function getStaticProps(dehydratedState) {
    const queryClient = new QueryClient()
    await queryClient.prefetchQuery('users', fetchUsers)
    
    return {
        props: { dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient).toString()}
    };
}
```

For individual ID's nothing worked, I left below:
It fetches a single user, but not with React Query.

```js
import { dehydrate } from 'react-query/hydration'
import Link from 'next/link'

const fetchUsers = () => {
    return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
}

function User({ user }){
    return (
        <div>{user.name}</div>
    )
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    const users = await res.json()

    const paths = users.map((user) => ({
        params: { id: user.id.toString() },
    }))

    return { paths, fallback: false }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${params.id}`)
    
    const user = await res.json()
  
    return { props: { user } }
}
  
export default User
```

The third part (this is the single ID fetch with hydrate, not simple Next.js)

```js
import { QueryClient } from "react-query"
import { dehydrate, useQuery } from "react-query"
import axios from "axios"

const userIdFetch = (props) => {
    return axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${props.id}`)
}

function User(user){
    const { isLoading, data, isError, error } = useQuery(['users', user.id], userIdFetch)
    console.log(user)
    
    return (
        <div></div>
    )
}
  
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    const users = await res.json()
  
    const paths = users.map((user) => ({
        params: { id: user.id.toString() },
    }))
  
    return { paths, fallback: false }
}
  
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${params.id}`)
    const userFetch = await res.json()
    
    const queryClient = new QueryClient()
    await queryClient.prefetchQuery('users', userFetch)

    return { 
        props: { dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient).toString()}
    }
}
  
export default User
```

Comment: Is `User` a page component (located under `pages` folder)?  Did you properly setup `ReactQueryCacheProvider` and `Hydrate` wrappers in `_app`? Can you also show that file's code?

Comment: So the first half is pages/users/index.js
And for dynamic it is pages/users/[id].js

It fetches a single ID, but not with React Query.
It works as a default NextJS fetch, however I want to get this with dehydrate.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "nothing worked"? Do you get any errors? Can you show the code you tried with React Query.

Comment: I have enclosed this as part 3. So what I am trying to fetch a single user based on ID with React-Query and fetch this particular user's details, f.e, name, surname, phone, etc.

Comment: In your last code block, `userFetch` has to be a function - it's currently plain JSON data. Modify `userFetch` so it's a function that makes the `fetch` request and returns the JSON data.

Comment: I have done this either, but does not work. Is there any way that you could help me to get this resolved? I totally stuck.